# Quels sont les noms communs ayant le plus de résultats sur Google ?

Tags: noms

Par exemple voici les nombres de résultats (en millions) pour des mots ayant déjà des hautes fréquences dans la langue :

- 1970 temps
- 1500 maison
- 1410 vie
- 1070 monde
- 656 enfant
- 629 chose
- 480 accord
- 492 besoin
- 426 amour
- 420 argent
- 389 père
- 383 nuit
- 246 gens
- 186 dieu
- 90 peur

Si les noms communs ayants le plus de résultats ne sont pas ceux ci mais d'autres comment les découvrir ?

Answer (score 2):

Le nombre total de résultats indiqué par Google est assez fiable quand on recherche un seul mot mais Google ne retournera jamais plus que quelques centaines de pages, quel que soit le mot clef choisi. Ces pages seront en plus sélectionnées en fonction de ton profil, de ton emplacement, etc.

Si tu veux d'autres chiffres de fréquence d'utilisation de mots, tu peux regarder du côté de Google Books ou la base [Lexique](http://www.lexique.org/).

Pour cette dernière, les trente noms communs les plus courants en français sont:

```
 1  2320.44 temps
 2  2039.25 fois
 3  2016.99 chose
 4  1918.16 peu
 5  1822.06 vie
 6  1633.34 homme
 7  1587.42 père
 8  1556.05 monde
 9  1486.77 femme
10  1461.57 jour
11  1409.09 mère
12  1327.22 ans
13  1314.62 tête
14  1271.57 yeux
15  1229.92 nuit
16  1221.42 dieu
17  1134.51 air
18  1083.08 soir
19  1075.34 main
20  1044.62 fille
21  1031.85 maison
22  1031.04 coup
23  1014.87 moment
24  1009.8 besoin
25  1003.6 gens
26   942.1 jours
27   889.0 hommes
28   886.4 accord
29   870.2 monsieur
30   859.0 peur
```

Cela dit, on voit que l'ordre de grandeur des occurrences des quelques mots qui apparaissent dans tes tests avec Google et mon extraction de Lexique sont assez proches.

On peut donc en déduire qu'on a peu de chances de trouver mieux que ***temps*** avec ta méthode.

Google Books permet de [télécharger des tables](https://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv3.html) à partir desquelles on peut extraire des statistiques d'usage par année.

Un classement sur les noms commençant par la lettre *A* utilisés depuis 1970 fait apparaître quelques mots différents de ceux obtenus avec Lexique, on a aussi quelques noms propres (ici Afrique et Allemagne) :

```
 1    15743129 ans_NOUN
 2    14240455 années_NOUN
 3    10108876 article_NOUN
 4     9255235 action_NOUN
 5     7911291 année_NOUN
 6     7838454 abord_NOUN
 7     7181193 A._NOUN
 8     7112454 auteur_NOUN
 9     6824954 an_NOUN
10     6818429 art_NOUN
11     6616257 activité_NOUN
12     6057271 Afrique_NOUN
13     5131070 avril_NOUN
14     4936990 activités_NOUN
15     4679245 accord_NOUN
16     4519093 âge_NOUN
17     4495427 analyse_NOUN
18     4481832 application_NOUN
19     4432028 administration_NOUN
20     4273175 août_NOUN
21     4201284 amour_NOUN
22     4012346 A_NOUN
23     3918979 Allemagne_NOUN
24     3917407 acte_NOUN
25     3885116 affaires_NOUN
26     3855744 absence_NOUN
27     3686579 auteurs_NOUN
28     3683295 armée_NOUN
29     3556928 autorité_NOUN
30     3468956 affaire_NOUN
```

Comment: C'est de lexique.org que j'ai tiré mes exemples. Je me suis laissé dire que google était un corpus plus près de ce que les gens se disent en conversation que ce qu'on (les auteurs) leur dit. Il est aussi MAJ perpétuellement et contient tout, les noms propres etc.

Comment: J'ai découvert la notion de fréquence en linguistique mais je ne la comprends pas faut d'unité de mesure. C'est des quoi par quoi ? occurrence par 1M de mots ?

Comment: Oui, il s'agit d'occurrences par million. Tu a mentionné noms communs dans ta question. Les noms propres sont plus difficiles à identifier et à associer à une langue. Google n'est sûrement pas plus près de ce que les gens se disent en conversation. Le meilleur corpus pour le déterminer est celui qui s'appuie sur les sous-titres de films.

Comment: http://www.lexique.org/databases/Lexique382/Manuel_Lexique3.html#__RefHeading___Toc152122352

Comment: je n'ai pas vérifié les autres mais il y a 2 fois "homme" dans cette liste, en position 6 et 27...

Comment: @jlliagre je vois vraiment mal comment des dialogues écris sur des thèmes extrêmement restreints que sont ceux du cinéma seraient plus représentatifs que l'ensemble du web.

Comment: La plupart des pages indexées par les moteurs de recherche ont un contenu absolument sans intérêt pour qui s'intéresse à la langue parlée ou écrite. Que tirer de catalogues de pièces détachées, de tarifs, de fichiers de code source généré automatiquement par des programmes, de notices de montage traduites automatiquement du chinois...

Comment: @LaurentS.Bien vu, il y a aussi *jour* dans ce cas. Je met ma réponse à jour. Il s'agissait en fait du même mot mais une fois au singulier et une fois au pluriel.